# How do I make a second domain controller authenticate and resolve dns lookups?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2016

I have recently added a second domain controller to a LAN.  Active directory and the DNS server is syncing/replicating with no errors but when the original domain controller is offline or down domain authentication no longer works nor does dns.  What am I missing in the configuration?

All that I know is that if a new user tries to login on a pc when the second dc is down they get a message that says something like a domain cannot be contacted.
The  DC2 does hosts all the same DNS zones that DC1 hosts.

*The get-addomaincontroller powershell command run on the second dc says true for dc1 but makes no mention of dc2 at all.

The Global Catalog is checked in the NTDS settings for both DC’s in the AD for Sites and Services.

DCDIAG /test:dns returns that everything has passed.

Power Shell Command Returns.
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | ft -prop name, site, IsGlobalCatalog, IsReadOnly  Returns that ReadOnly is False for both servers.

Nslookup Returns:

C:\Windows\system32>nslookup -type=SRV _kerberos._tcp.oicl.local 192.168.1.2

Server:  OiclDc02.oicl.local
Address:  192.168.1.2

_kerberos._tcp.oicl.local       SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = oicldc01.oicl.local
_kerberos._tcp.oicl.local       SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = OiclDc02.oicl.local
_kerberos._tcp.oicl.local       SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = OiclDc01.oicl.local
_kerberos._tcp.oicl.local       SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 100
          port           = 88
          svr hostname   = oicldc02.oicl.local
oicldc01.oicl.local     internet address = 192.168.1.7
OiclDc02.oicl.local     internet address = 192.168.1.2
OiclDc01.oicl.local     internet address = 192.168.1.7
oicldc02.oicl.local     internet address = 192.168.1.2

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: There are other SRV records that need to be checked besides Kerberos, such as _ldap._tcp and entries under the _msdcs subdomain. Browse through these parts in the DNS management console and check you have both servers entered at every opportunity.

Answer (score 3):

Have the DNS settings on all machines been updated to use the 2nd domain controller for DNS? If you're not sure you can run `ipconfig /all` on a client to see. If only one "DNS Sever" is listed, that's a problem. For DHCP clients, update your scopes to include the 2nd DC as a secondary DNS servers. At the next DHCP refresh clients will get the 2nd DNS server. For static clients, you will need to add the 2nd DNS server manually.

```
C:\> ipconfig /all
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
<rows of other stuff>
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.2.3.4
                                       10.2.3.5
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

**Edit 10/3**

Does the authentication failure affect ALL applications or just one? Some older legacy apps could have a dependency on the PDC FSMO holder.

Does the DC2 host all the same DNS zones that DC1 hosts?

Other thing to check, is 2nd DC also a Global Catalog server? Invoke `get-addomaincontroller` which will return about 20 lines, one of which will read `IsGlobalCatalog: True`. If it is not a GC, launch AD Sites & Services MMC, navigate to the NTDS Settings object for that DC, check the box for `is global catalog`.

Otherwise I would suspect a network issue between the clients and this 2nd DC, or your statement about it successfully replicating AD & DNS may not be correct. Does `DCDIAG /test:dns` report any errors when run from the 2nd DC?

You can add new info that you find by editing your original post.

**Edit 10/4**

What do you get when you run the following command from one of the workstations that had the problem? Run the command twice, each time replace `10.2.3.4` with the IP of each DC, and `yourdom.com` with the name of your domain.

```
nslookup -type=SRV _kerberos._tcp.yourdom.com 10.2.3.4
```

Is DC2 a full DC or readOnly DC? Run this from either DC:

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | ft -prop name, site, IsGlobalCatalog, IsReadOnly
```

Comment: This what I have with  1.7 as the original dc server and 1.2 as the new dc                                                                                                                         DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.7
                                                  192.168.1.2

Comment: @Mark: We have no idea if that's correct. Are those the ip addresses of the DC/DNS servers? If so, have you configured all domain members to use both?

Comment: Yes they are both dns servers and domain controllers.

Comment: There is not a good way to display the entire ipconfig /all return in the serverfault comment box without running out of room.

Comment: Sorry, to answer your original question, Yes, all of the client computers have been updated to use the 2nd domain controller.